# ChartJS change monthly labels as time/date

Tags: javascript, chart.js

index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script  src="assets/js/script-java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script-java.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
      labels: ["January","Fberuary","March"],
      datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [120, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],

      }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {}
});
```

output:
[image]

Here are the code, as you can see,  my labels are Monthly names, how can I replace it with time/data? What I am trying to achieve is like stock market chart where you can see what date and time a data went it.

Thanks

EDIT: I just saw a documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

I tried it, the code script is now:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
      datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [120, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],

      }]

  },

  // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

But now, nothing is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',

// The data for our dataset
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        // data : [10,20]
        data: [{x: new Date(), y:15},{x: moment().add(10,'days'), y:50},
        {x : moment().add(15,'days'), y:20}],

    }]

},

// Configuration options go here
  options: {
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                // unit: 'month',
                  displayFormats: {
                      quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                  }
              }
          }]
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's a static code, like what I have said, the time/date will be based on when the data went it.

Comment: Are you referencing that the data that you acquire will have no date/time value just data only and you intend to take the system date/time for the labels?

Comment: Yes. I just saw ChartJS has some documentation on how to do it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html, but still I couldnt figure it out

Comment: I just edited my question. Please check it, Thank you

Comment: Did you add moment.js? Add moment js above the chart js.

Comment: I have edited the answer in accordance to your change in post.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I already added moment.js ( i've already edited my index.php ). , then I replace my script and added yours, but still not working, the output is empty, nothing is showing. but i checked the console and there are some errors:  http://prntscr.com/ltc1g6

Comment: I checked everything and found out that the only difference between our codes is the CDN we both are using. Use  this cdn instead/
 <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>